# Batch iphone application creation

Tags: iphone, xcode, batch-processing

I have built an application that show you information based on te images and database that are included in the bundle of this application. I want to build a whole set of these applications only with different images and databases, but I do not want to create an xcode project for each of these application. Because if I make a change in the application I will have to build all the apps again. I want to be able to build the application using a batch script and then duplicate this and build it for the other applications with a different database and different images. This is what I did so far. I have built the app and then copied the resulting build results. I cleaned these up a bit (for every action it has a cd statement and a setenv statement, which you only need once). But I can't get the thing to run because it uses built in function to execute certain statements, namely:

```
<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility>
```

and

```
builtin-infoPlistUtility
```

Can anybody help me to execute these command from a batch file?

Comment: I guess this is how the App Store gets spammed with dozens of apps at once from the same developer, and how one developer has over 7000 apps in the store right now.

Comment: Even if it is possible to mess up the App Store this way (which is Apple's problem, not ours), it is still desirable to replace Xcode with a custom build chain, e.g. as part of a cross platform build.

Comment: I'm just trying to automate my iOS build, so I can keep using my apps after a week! (: (I'm using a free account.)